# Spring security authentication through database with custom user

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, authentication, spring-security

I'm using Spring security and annotation to authenticate user through database and Ldap.
In detail, since Ldap doesn't allow attributes retrieving, I check if user (unique code) and password are correct through a Ldap search and then use my database to load authorities. So all user into my database exist into Ldap, but if a user exists into Ldap and not in my database I show a specific page.
This is the actual code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true, prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:application.properties" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


    @Autowired
    AuthenticationConfiguration authenticationConfiguration;

    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration implements
    AuthenticationProvider {

        @Autowired
        private UserServices userServices;
        @Autowired
        LdapServices ldapServices;

        @Override
        public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
            Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
            String name = authentication.getName();
            String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
            boolean isFind = ldapServices.ldapSearch(name, password);                           
            if (isFind){
                com.domain.User user = userServices.getByUsersEnabled(name);
                if (user!=null)
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_"+user.getRole().getRole()));          
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, authorities);
            }           
            else return null;
        }


        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
            return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
        }
    }

    @Autowired
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationConfiguration);
        }

...web services authentication
```

I have simple user and I would like to add some information like name/surname and email. I read that I have to implement `UserDetails` and `loadUserByUsername` of `UserDetailsService` interface, but how can I merge `loadUserByUsername` with my code? In this way I can show name and surname instead of user code. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed  `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, authorities);` with  `return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password, authorities);` and in my HTML page I use `sec:authentication="principal.name"` to retrieve name parameter

Answer (score 0):

I was also having some problems with a similar issue, and then I found a great article that helped me to get it done.
The article is here: [spring-ldap-custom-authorities](https://spapas.github.io/2013/10/14/spring-ldap-custom-authorities/)

I hope it helps. Basically, you will have to do the authentication process on the LDAP server, and you must create a "`CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator`", so you can get the user details later.

You would have to have something like this on your XML:

```
<beans:bean id="ldapAuthProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <beans:bean
            class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator">
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="contextSource" />
            <beans:property name="userSearch" ref="userSearch" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:constructor-arg>
    <beans:constructor-arg>
        <!-- User roles -->
        <beans:bean class="com.company.package.CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator" />
    </beans:constructor-arg>
</beans:bean>
```

And later on your CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator you would deal with the user rolers. Something like this:

```
@Service("myAuthPopulator")
public class CustomLdapAuthoritiesPopulator implements LdapAuthoritiesPopulator {
    @Transactional(readOnly=true)
    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(DirContextOperations userData, String username) {

        Set<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        try {

            User user = userService.findUserByUsername(username);

            if (user == null) {
               // User doesn't exist in the database
            } else {

               // user exists

                //get roles
                Set<UserRole> userRoles = user.getUserRoles();

                //add roles
                for (UserRole userRole : userRoles) {
                    authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole.getRole()));
                }

                return authorities;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            //exception
        }
        return authorities;
    }

}
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/17660666)

Comment: Hi @ProkashSarkar, thanks for your reply. I have edited the answer and added some code to it. I guess it is better now.